# phpmailer echo useless information on the target website

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I create a simple webpage to test phpmailer.
below is a simple form

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    <button type="submit">
<form>
```

after I click the button.the sendmail.php is like below

```
<?php
            include "./class.phpmailer.php";
            $name=$_GET['name'];

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
            $mail->Host = "smtp.****.com";
            $mail->Port = "465";  
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "*@***.com";
            $mail->Password = "google";


            $mail->AddReplyTo("atekul@xxx.com", "xxx");
            $mail->AddAddress("atekul@xxx.com");
            $mail->SetFrom("sentmail@xxx.com", "xxx");

            $mail->IsHTML(false);
            $mail->Subject = "HotelOrder";
            $mail->MsgHTML("Orderinfo");

            if(!$mail->Send())
            {
                echo "fail: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "success";
            }    
        ?>
```

all the things are great,and the email sent successful ..
but the annoy thing is that the php script display lost of useless information on the webpage like this

2014-07-31 13.29 Server-> clientL220 ***********
smtp545-123  blah blah

but I don't want the user to see information like this.anyway to avoid or hide those information on the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this line:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks.I try this <div style="display:none"></div>.it works .but I guess your way is better..

Answer (score 0):

you have to comment, remove following line, or set it to 0:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
// It's used to display errors and messages.
```

in the phpmailer web-site you can read:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
```

Comment: Thx,by the way i'm a starter in web page design.If I want to use css and div to make a webpage from a PSD file.where should I start.